# How can change text size of days inside of date time picker dialog?

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have `date time picker dialog` in my project. The size of `dialog` is well for phones. But, it's small for tablet screen. I did special `style.xml` for tablet screen and I did successfully bigger `button` and `font size of button`. But, I can't change `text size` of days successfully. How can I do this?

[image]

```
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (tabletSize) {
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.date_time_picker, this, year, month, day);
     datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_corner);
        return datePickerDialog;
    }
```

sw600dp/styles.xml

```
  <style name="date_time_picker">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: same issue im facing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to increate the text size by setting

```
    <style name="AppTheme.DatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/date_text_appearance</item>
    </style>
```

And then set the dateTextAppearance:

```
<style name="date_text_appearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:dateTextAppearance"></item>
```